# insert records for day of week within date range

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to do this. Been doing research, can't find anything for it that I can figure out how to use.

I have a startdate, enddate, recurringday, customer

startdate = 04/01/2013

enddate = 04/30/2013

customer = john

recurringday = monday

I want to insert a record for john every monday within startdate and enddate, can someone please help me? new to vb.net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use DayofWeek function to check if today's day is monday. Then use Insert command.

```
Dim startdate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01 Apr 2013")
Dim enddate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("30 Apr 2013")

Dim DofW = Now.DayOfWeek()
dim recurringday = "Monday"

If now >= startdate And now <= enddate Then
  If DofW = recurringday Then
    'Insert Record
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sweety suggested .DayofWeek, but I am not sure his method fulfills your requirements. Try this:

```
    Dim StartDate As DateTime = CDate("01 Apr 2013")
    Dim FinishDate As DateTime = CDate("30 Apr 2013")

    Dim RecurringDay = "Monday"

    Dim Period = FinishDate.Subtract(StartDate).TotalDays

    Dim CurrentDate As DateTime

    For Counter As Integer = 0 To Period
        CurrentDate = StartDate.AddDays(Counter)
        If CurrentDate.DayOfWeek = RecurringDay Then
            'Insert Record
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Dim StartDate As DateTime = #4/1/2013#
    Dim FinishDate As DateTime = #4/30/2013#

    Dim RecurringDay As Integer = DayOfWeek.Monday

    'force to first RecurringDay
    If RecurringDay < StartDate.DayOfWeek Then StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(7)
    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(RecurringDay - StartDate.DayOfWeek)

    Do While StartDate <= FinishDate
        Debug.WriteLine(StartDate.ToLongDateString)
        'insert record
        StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(7)
    Loop
```